# G++ not detected

Tags: python, machine-learning, g++, theano

I am working on some neural networks. But my dataset is same 95 features and about 120 datasets.

So while importing theano i get warning g++ not detected and it will degrade the performance.

Do this will effect even a small dataset?

I will have a 2-3 hidden layers.

My shape of neural network will be (95, 200,200, 4)

I hope to hear.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you need to install `mingw` to support g++. Usually, it is advisable to use Anaconda distribution to install Python. Theano works with Python3.4 or older versions. You can use `conda install` command to install mingw.